# Contact Form 7 - Form name blank

Tags: plugins, customization, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm using **WordPress 4.2.2** and the "Contact Form 7" plugin **version 4.2.1**. But when my contact form shortcode outputs the html code the `name=""` attribute is blank and W3C html validator is giving me errors because of this. How can I fix this?

Comment: wow. I bring up an error in a plugin and I get down voted! Nice community of people willing to help..

Comment: Like every community we have specific rules which can be found in the help section, specifically what's considered to be [on / off topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Plugin questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** This has been fixed in [Contact Form 7 - v4.2.2](http://contactform7.com/2015/07/30/contact-form-7-422/)

The issue is that whenever Contact Form 7 generates the form shortcode it doesn't create a name attribute and it doesn't seem to fallback to using the title attribute of the shortcode. HTML 5 doesn't like empty name attributes.

One solution until this is fixed could be to add an attribute to your Contact Form 7 shortcode `html_name` and give it some kind of string value. This will solve the validation issue. It's something WPCF7 should handle but it works in the meantime.

```
[contact-form-7 id="4" title="Contact Form" html_name="Contact Form 1"]
```

Comment: Your talking about an input field name. I am talking about a the MAIN form name. I can set it by adding html_name="something" in the shortcode but if you dont add that by default the plugin exports and empty form name which is improper markup and will never validate. This is an error in the plugin and I have submitted it to the plugin author.

Comment: @agon024 Howdy_McGee meens the cf7 form shortcode, not an input definition. So the form name will be set and the HTML is valid. This is a workaround, WPCF7 should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have some mistake on form creation

it should be like

```
[text* text-1 class:form-control placeholder "Name"]
```

Where `text-1` is name attribute.

So check your end and fix issue.